# Is there a limit to the amount/number of photons that can be measured/detected in one single point in space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, measurements, density

I've heard that there is no limit to photon density. So if we have a bunch of photons going in the same direction, or with some going in opposite directions but with arbitrarily low energy(so that a black hole doesn't form), then can we in theory make a measurement and measure arbitrarily many photons at one point in space?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/287369/how-many-photons-can-exist-in-a-cubic-box-of-unit-volume-simultaneously?rq=1